# copy() Warning Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php

I'm trying to save the external images on my site

I have this code:

```
$file = $_GET['url'];
$newfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/images/name.jpg';

if ( copy($file, $newfile) ) {
    echo "Copy saved";
}else{
    echo "copy failed";
}
```

it works well and save images on my server OK, but when I try to use inside `FOR`, i have this warning:

```
Warning: copy(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/animesad/public_html/bot/getimg.php on line 18
```

My code is:

```
<?php
require "../functions.php";
$p = $_GET['p'];

$url = "http://www.mysite.net/en/movie/page/".$p."/";
$source = curl_get_contents("$url");

preg_match_all('#<li title="(.*?)"><a href#',$source,$name); //outputs title post
preg_match_all('#<img src="(.*?)" width="140" height="200"/>#',$source,$img); //outputs img url

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
//print_r($name[1][$i]."<hr />");  //that code show the names OK. (Title posts);

$namefile = slugify($name[1][$i]); //slugify is my function that convert titles in slug.

$newfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/img/'.$namefile.'.jpg';

    if ( copy($file, $newfile) ) {
        echo "copy saved <hr />";
    }else{
        echo "copy failed <hr />";
    }

}

?>
```

Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot your $file

```
$file = $_GET['url'];

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){

    $namefile = slugify($name[1][$i]); //slugify is my function that convert titles in slug.

    $newfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/img/'.$namefile.'.jpg';

    if ( copy($file, $newfile) ) {
        echo "copy saved <hr />";
    }else{
        echo "copy failed <hr />";
    }
}
```

Comment: was a mistake, thank you, I had to replace $file for $img[1][$i];